# Instance variable goes out of scope inside method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, scope, argument-passing

I have this method which gets called from a different class:

```
-(void)artworkInfo:(NSNumber *)pos{
    [image setImage:(UIImage *)[[mainDelegate.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pos]image]];
    [pos release];
}
```

I put debugger stop-points on all three lines. When debugging, just after the method is called and before `setImage` is called, hovering the mouse over `pos` in the method definition and in the `setImage` line shows the correct value which was sent from the method call. But, when I advance in the debugger and the next line `[image setImage...]` gets run hovering over both `pos`s shows "Out of scope", and the app, therefore, does not display the image it should. Why does this happen?

**EDIT:** Well, it seems my issue may just be in how the method is called in the class, because even a hardcoded value is not producing the image in the method, but if I copy and paste that line into `viewDidLoad:`, it does. Why would that line work in `viewDidLoad:`, but not when it is called in the method it's in now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be releasing an object passed as parameter into a method, it's bad practice. And you should't cast a NSNumber object into a NSUInteger type.

You may want something like...

```
[pos intValue]//This will return the integer value of pos.
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that is what I want. Unfortunately it seems that wasn't really the problem :/ I edited my question with what is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. You should always retain objects that you receive.
2. You shouldn't be casting NSNumber to NSUInteger. Use [pos intValue] to get the integer value.
3. You shouldn't be releasing pos in a situation like this unless you've explicitly retained it.

Comment: What do you mean "You should always retain objects that you receive"? I don't see anything that should obviously be retained here (though the `release` is surely wrong as you say).

Comment: It could be a case of personal preference, but if a method receives an object reference, the first thing I do is retain it. I then release it at the end of the method scope.

Comment: To be honest, that sounds like needless inefficiency to me. If you ever actually need to do it, that's symptomatic of a larger problem with your memory management. It's certainly not normal — look at any Apple sample code or open-source code from major Cocoa developers and you'll see it's not done.

Comment: It's possible you're correct. How would you determine what needs to be retained and what doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that image inside mapAnnotations was freed before. I don't know why are you releasing pos, since it is a parameter so it has an implicit autorelease. Try removing that `[pos release]`